# Redis session not available

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, session, redis

I have an issue where sessions were not getting stored in the redisstore., Am trying to use Redis Session for the OAUTH Implementation. Below is the code, where am trying to use redis store to save the sessions. However I can see redis client is connected message, but in reality no keys were getting stored in the redisStore.

```
Start.js file:
const config = require('config');
const security = require('./express/infrastructure/security-factory');
const { enable } = require('./app-insights');

// App Insights needs to be enabled as early as possible as it monitors other libraries as well
const appInsights = enable();
appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext = userId => {
  const validatedId = userId.replace(/[,;=| ]+/g, '_');
  const key = appInsights.defaultClient.context.keys.userAuthUserId;
  appInsights.defaultClient.context.tags[key] = validatedId;
};

const app = require('./server')(security(appInsights), appInsights),
  fs = require('fs'),
  defaultPort = '3000',
  port = process.env.PORT || defaultPort,
  https = require('https'),
  http = require('http');

// reverse proxy handles tls in non local environments
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const crtLocation = config.get('certs.crt'),
    keyLocation = config.get('certs.key'),
    cert = fs.readFileSync(crtLocation),
    key = fs.readFileSync(keyLocation);
  https.createServer({ key, cert }, app).listen(port);
} else {
  http.createServer(app).listen(port);
}


Server.JS file.

const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const HttpStatus = require('http-status-codes');
const express = require('express');
const route = require('./express/app');
const roles = require('./express/infrastructure/roles');
const csurf = require('csurf');
const moment = require('moment');
const healthcheck = require('./express/infrastructure/health-info');
const { Logger } = require('@1234/nodejs-logging');
const { ApiCallError, ApiErrorFactory } = require('./express/infrastructure/errors');
const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('config'));
const { redisStore, getAllActiveSessions } = require('./express/config/redis');

const app = express();

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

let csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie: true });
const errorFactory = ApiErrorFactory('server.js');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  csrfProtection = (req, res, next) => {
    next();
  };
}

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  let error = null;
  if (err instanceof ApiCallError) {
    error = err;
  } else if (err.code === 'EBADCSRFTOKEN') {
    error = errorFactory.createForbiddenError(err);
  } else {
    error = errorFactory.createServerError(err);
  }

  const msg = JSON.stringify({ error: error.toString(), cause: error.remoteError ? error.remoteError.toString() : '' });

  if (req.xhr) {
    res.status(error.status).send({ error: error.remoteError || error.message });
  } else {
    res.status(error.status);
    res.render('error', {
      title: error.status,
      message: error.detailedMessage,
      msg,
      moment
    });
  }
}

function sessionCheck(req, res, next) {
    const sess = req.sessionID
    req.session.name =sess;
    return req;
}


module.exports = (security, appInsights) => {
  const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
  const startTime = Date.now();

  // use helmet for security
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(helmet.noCache());
  app.use(helmet.frameguard());
  app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'express/mvc/views'));

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
  const HALF_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 30;
  const NODE_ENV = 'development';
  const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV !== 'development';
  const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'sssss',
    name: 'session1',
    cookie: {
      maxAge: Number(HALF_HOUR),
      secure: IN_PROD,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: true
    },
    store: redisStore,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false
  });
  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false}));

  // parse application/json - REMOVE THIS! https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  // app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(sessionMiddleware);
  app.use(sessionCheck);
  // enable the dist folder to be accessed statically
  app.use(express.static('dist/ccpay-bubble'));
  app.use('/health/readiness', (req, res) => res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ status: 'UP' }));
  app.use('/logout', security.logout());
  app.use('/oauth2/callback', security.OAuth2CallbackEndpoint());

  // allow access origin
  // @TODO - This will only take effect when on "dev" environment, but not on "prod"
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Auth-Dev, CSRF-Token');
      next();
    });
  }

  // make all routes available via this imported module
  app.use('/api', security.protectWithAnyOf(roles.allRoles, ['/**']), csrfProtection, route(appInsights));


  app.use(errorHandler);

  

  return app;
};


EXPRES/Config/Redis.js File.
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

const redisStore = new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient,ttl :  86400});

redisClient.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(`redis connected 1${redisClient.connected}`);
}).on('error', error => {
  console.log(error);
});

redisClient.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('redis client is ready');
});

function getAllActiveSessions() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    redisStore.all(function(err, sessions) {
      if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(sessions);
      });
    });
}

module.exports = { redisStore, getAllActiveSessions };


Express/Infra/Security.js File.

Security.prototype.OAuth2CallbackEndpoint = function OAuth2CallbackEndpoint() {
  const self = { opts: this.opts };

  return function ret(req, res, next) { 
}

Issues:  
1. When I run the application Redis session is not created and in redis-cli, i cannot see any keys.
2. Req.session is undefined in the Security.js File. How can I access req.session here.
3. If I run the health check directly, like  https://localhost:3000/health/readiness, Then in the redis-cli, when I check for the keys session is getting created.

Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: Isn't ttl :  260 too low?

Comment: Hi @FurkanO any help on this one please

Comment: @RohitDalal, its a typo. i changed ttl to 86400.

Comment: 260 milliseconds for the key to live, your key is getting destroyed within 1 seconds. Kindly increase the ttl(Time To Live) value

Comment: Whats the name of redis package you are using?

Comment: @RohitDalal am using "redis": "^3.0.2", npm.,  "connect-redis": "^5.1.0",, "express": "^4.16.4", "express-session": "^1.17.1",

Comment: const redis = require('redis')
const session = require('express-session')


let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

Comment: While creating redisStore it request session from express-session package.

Comment: yes @RohitDalal, may I please know what went wrong ?

Comment: I dont see session variable getting passed while creating redisStore.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session, here there is an example of exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RohitDalal, I tried the same, bnut still i cannot see an keys created in redis-cli. I have used express-session only, but some how it is not getting created. app.use(sessionMiddleware); is the one which is calling the express session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229163/discussion-between-santosh-shiva-kumar-and-rohit-dalal).

Comment: hi @Yxven any help on this one pls

Comment: HI @PokatilovArt  any help please

Comment: hi @FurkanO any help pls